# Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial hard crashing on ACER E3-11-P0D8

Tags: kernel

About a month ago I installed the latest Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial on my ACER E3-11-P0D8 laptop. Since then, it randomly freeze up while I work. It generally takes 10-20 mins to do that.

Out of frustration, I started to change the kernel. It seems that every >4.0 kernel is freezing up my system. Now I am stable at 3.19.8 from [the mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

Now I want to use the latest kernel. How can I make my laptop work with the latest kernel?

1. Does crash dump work in this kind of situation? If so, how can I grab a crash dump after switching off the laptop manually and starting it again?
2. Where should I submit this crash dump? Launchpad?

My system specs:

- Intel pentium quad core N3540
- 4 GB DDR3
- 500 GB HDD

Comment: I suggest reporting a but to launchpad. Install the problem kernel and run `ubuntu-bug linux`.

Comment: thankfully it gives me enough time to do that. But would they know about the problem by this process ?

Comment: Yes, the information will be uploaded. You will need to describe the problem. Probably they will suggest to test kernel 4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an Acer E3-111, and I upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS a couple days ago, and had the same freezing issues as being described here. I'm assuming that your laptop is an E3-112, based on a bug submission on Launchpad that was clearly you.

I was running BIOS version 1.35 when I first upgraded. I installed the version 1.37 BIOS from Acer's website, and I've been going for about a day now without any freezes. The description of the BIOS version 1.37 is "Update EC to version v2.6(improve compatibility of battery charging)." For the E3-112, the latest BIOS is version 1.16, and has a similar description "Update EC to version v1.7(improve compatibility of battery charging)." Based on the bug submission on Launchpad (if that was indeed you), it looks like you were using an old BIOS, so a BIOS upgrade might do the trick.

I'll update if the problem reappears, or if I just didn't wait long enough to see it.

As an aside, to flash the Acer BIOS, you have to be running Windows. When I bought this machine, the first thing I did was take out the original hard drive and put in an SSD with Xubuntu. So all I had to do was put back in the original hard drive with Windows to flash the BIOS. If you overwrote your original hard drive, you might be in trouble here.

System:
Acer E3-111-P60S
Intel Pentium N3530
4GB RAM

Current Linux Kernel 4.4.0-34-generic

Update: It's been about 4 days, and everything is fine. I'm calling this resolved unless OP updates their BIOS and has contradicting results.

[link to the associated launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1592442)

Comment: please update after a while if that resolved your issue. I wasn't having any luck on v4 kernels

Comment: It's been a couple of days now, and  it hasn't frozen on me yet. Have you tried upgrading to the current BIOS?

Comment: thanks for the update. i have updated my bios. Haven't installed ubuntu yet ( previous install is a mess ), but it seems like the answer.